# Traffic replicated across multiple VLANs - ASA

Tags: cisco-asa

Have a switch connected to a FW via a trunk.  The receiving interface on the FW is a PO with subif's for each VLAN on the trunk.  We have a flow we want to track coming in on VLAN 306 / SEC_Data, leaving on VLAN 307 / SEC_TELEPHONY, packet-tracer verifies these are the actual in/out if's.  With this information in hand we setup a capture on both if's (mapping to VLAN 306 and 307 respectively).  The result is that we capture identical flows on both interfaces.  I'm not sure if this is an ASA capture logic issue, or if it isn't, how this is possible..

**Traffic Pattern**

**SRC -** 10.97.48.188

**DST -** 10.97.85.11

**OVER -** TCP 1099

**Interface setup**

```
Port-channel2.306        SEC_Data               10.97.48.1      255.255.240.0   manual
Port-channel2.307        SEC_TELEPHONY          10.97.80.1      255.255.240.0   manual
```

**Packet tracer validating in/out if's**

```
packet-tracer input SEC_Data tcp 10.97.48.188 1024 10.97.63.33 1099 det
Result:
input-interface: SEC_Data
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: SEC_TELEPHONY
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: allow
```

**Capture strings**

```
capture test2 type raw-data interface SEC_Data [Capturing - 0 bytes] 
  match tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 
capture sectel type raw-data interface SEC_TELEPHONY [Capturing - 0 bytes] 
  match tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099
```

**Capture results**

```
capture test2 type raw-data interface SEC_Data [Capturing - 1728 bytes] 
  match tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 
capture sectel type raw-data interface SEC_TELEPHONY [Capturing - 1728 bytes] 
  match tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 

NY-CORE-FW1# sh cap test2

16 packets captured

   1: 15:33:30.311751       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: S 1531525431:1531525431(0) win 29200 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3343832270 0,nop,wscale 7> 
   2: 15:33:30.311888       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: S 4154378133:4154378133(0) ack 1531525432 win 14480 <mss 1380,sackOK,timestamp 1852592717 3343832270,nop,wscale 7> 
   3: 15:33:30.312193       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 4154378134 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832271 1852592717> 
   4: 15:33:30.343274       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 1531525432:1531525439(7) ack 4154378134 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832302 1852592717> 
   5: 15:33:30.343335       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 1531525439 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592749 3343832302> 
   6: 15:33:30.343427       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: P 4154378134:4154378153(19) ack 1531525439 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592749 3343832302> 
   7: 15:33:30.343610       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 4154378153 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832302 1852592749> 
   8: 15:33:30.344281       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 1531525439:1531525457(18) ack 4154378153 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832303 1852592749> 
   9: 15:33:30.344357       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 1531525457:1531525507(50) ack 4154378153 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832303 1852592749> 
  10: 15:33:30.344418       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 1531525507 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592750 3343832303> 
  11: 15:33:30.344556       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: P 4154378153:4154378380(227) ack 1531525507 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592750 3343832303> 
  12: 15:33:30.372371       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 1531525507:1531525522(15) ack 4154378380 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832331 1852592750> 
  13: 15:33:30.412316       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 1531525522 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592818 3343832331> 
  14: 15:33:45.374126       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: F 1531525522:1531525522(0) ack 4154378380 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343847332 1852592818> 
  15: 15:33:45.374492       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: F 4154378380:4154378380(0) ack 1531525523 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852607779 3343847332> 
  16: 15:33:45.374766       802.1Q vlan#306 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 4154378381 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343847333 1852607779> 
16 packets shown
NY-CORE-FW1# sh cap sectel

16 packets captured

   1: 15:33:30.311797       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: S 3575611247:3575611247(0) win 29200 <mss 1380,sackOK,timestamp 3343832270 0,nop,wscale 7> 
   2: 15:33:30.311888       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: S 3333267844:3333267844(0) ack 3575611248 win 14480 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 1852592717 3343832270,nop,wscale 7> 
   3: 15:33:30.312209       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 3333267845 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832271 1852592717> 
   4: 15:33:30.343289       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 3575611248:3575611255(7) ack 3333267845 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832302 1852592717> 
   5: 15:33:30.343335       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 3575611255 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592749 3343832302> 
   6: 15:33:30.343411       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: P 3333267845:3333267864(19) ack 3575611255 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592749 3343832302> 
   7: 15:33:30.343625       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 3333267864 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832302 1852592749> 
   8: 15:33:30.344281       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 3575611255:3575611273(18) ack 3333267864 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832303 1852592749> 
   9: 15:33:30.344373       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 3575611273:3575611323(50) ack 3333267864 win 229 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832303 1852592749> 
  10: 15:33:30.344418       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 3575611323 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592750 3343832303> 
  11: 15:33:30.344556       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: P 3333267864:3333268091(227) ack 3575611323 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592750 3343832303> 
  12: 15:33:30.372386       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: P 3575611323:3575611338(15) ack 3333268091 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343832331 1852592750> 
  13: 15:33:30.412316       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: . ack 3575611338 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852592818 3343832331> 
  14: 15:33:45.374141       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: F 3575611338:3575611338(0) ack 3333268091 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343847332 1852592818> 
  15: 15:33:45.374492       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.85.11.1099 > 10.97.48.188.41956: F 3333268091:3333268091(0) ack 3575611339 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1852607779 3343847332> 
  16: 15:33:45.374766       802.1Q vlan#307 P0 10.97.48.188.41956 > 10.97.85.11.1099: . ack 3333268092 win 237 <nop,nop,timestamp 3343847333 1852607779> 
16 packets shown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is more about "ASA capture logic issue", not "Traffic replicated across multiple VLANs".

---

I am telling you more:

1. The two following captures (on interface SEC_Data, and similar thoughts for interface SEC_TELEPHONY) are the same although we swap the position of source and destination hosts.

   `capture test3 interface SEC_Data match tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099`

   `capture test4 interface SEC_Data match tcp host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 host 10.97.48.188`

   Capture test3 seems to be more logical, because (traffic from) host 10.97.48.188 comes from interface SEC_Data and we correctly put it in the src-address position of the command while host 10.97.85.11 (TCP 1099) is at the des-address position.

   However, capture test4 results in same outputs as test3 does. We know its logic sounds "wrong" as we put the host 10.97.85.11 (TCP 1099) at the src-address position (while capturing interface is SEC_Data) and host 10.97.48.188 at the des-address.

   => ***The traffic flow/logic of ASA capture is not like those of ASA access-list***. With access-list, if you put hosts in wrong order, it will not work at all.

   *To me, the capture feature cares more about whether host A or host B resides in the capturing interface and all traffic to/from them rather than whether a SYNC packet is originally generated from the capturing interface (and the correct/real positions of hosts).*
2. To get a better understanding, you can use an access-list with capture to see how capture works with traffic flow.

   Clear all captures and create a new one sectel2 which has the same result with sectel1 but different positions of hots (See point 1. above)

   `capture sectel2 interface SEC_TELEPHONY match tcp host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 host 10.97.48.188`

   Create two dummy ACL lines below. They are harmless because they are not applied to any interface:

   `access-list Data-Telephony extended permit tcp host 10.97.48.188 host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099`

   `access-list Telephony-Data extended permit tcp host 10.97.85.11 eq 1099 host 10.97.48.188`

   Apply two lines above to new captures and then generate the traffic:

   `capture sectel3 access-list Data-Telephony interface SEC_TELEPHONY`

   `capture sectel4 access-list Telephony-Data interface SEC_TELEPHONY`

   **Results:**

   - Captures sectel1 and sectel2 have the same outputs.
   - Capture sectel3 contains all packets (starting with a SYNC packet) from 10.97.48.188 to 10.97.85.11 at TCP 1099 (only one direction due to access-list Data-Telephony).
   - Capture sectel4 contains all packets (starting with a SYNC + ACK packet) from 10.97.85.11 at TCP 1099 to 10.97.48.188 (only one direction due to access-list Telephony-Data).
   - Combine the outputs of sectel3 and sectel4, you will see they are the same with sectel1 or sectel2.

I hope you get the idea and it is helpful!

**Edit:**
I believe that the following two images will clear this up:

1. What you are concerning/thinking:
   [image: Capture Traffic ASA 1]

   2. However, this is what exactly it is:

[image: Capture Traffic ASA 2]

Comment: Hung, thanks for taking so much time, it's much appreciated!  I actually understand what you're saying here but I don't believe it's really speaking to my particular question.  Your examples appear to focus on directionality of capture logic, but in my case there are two separate interfaces altogether.  So - no, traffic tagged for 306 in bound, should not also show up tagged for 307 and coming in on that interface as well and to me that's not a directionality thing.  Let me know if that makes sense or if I'm missing the mark on your response!

Comment: @AL I have added two images to demonstrate what I wrote in the answer of how traffic flows and how capture works. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @AL Please let me know it you still have any concerns.

Comment: Hung, I have to again thank you for the time you're taking on this, basically the ASA capture logic is bi-directional - so as long as either the SRC or DST (in that pairing) are present coming through an IF - it will get captured.  So even if host A lives on IF A, and B on IF B - the exact same packets will show up on captures applied to watch A<->B traffic on both IF A and B - so in this case things likes IF name and .Q tag aren't necessarily accurate?? Please confirm.  This seems like a questionable functionality... especially if trying to t-shoot .Q tagging

Comment: @AL "So even if host A lives on IF A, and B on IF B - the exact same packets will show up on captures applied to watch A<->B traffic on both IF A and B" => It is correct, and

If you look at the time value in your two captures above, you will see a very very small difference of time when traffic passed from one Interface to another interface (1: 15:33:30.311751 vs 1: 15:33:30.311797 and so on). Sometimes, these values are the same, it may be because the capture or ASA does not support to show more digits after the decimal point "."

Answer (score 2):

To me, this looks perfectly normal.

I don't think that these captures are identical.

Looking at the TCP headers of the the first frame (TCP SYN), you can see that -  although all other properties are identical - the sequence numbers are different.

EDIT:
Oh.. there is also MSS clamping going on - ASA rewrites the MSS field from 1460 to 1380, on both the SYN segment from the initiator and the SYN-ACK segment from the responder.

I think this is ASA's *TCP sequence number randomization* at work.

EDIT:
And the ASA performs some TCP MSS manipulation, too.

Other than that, I would sincerely hope that all other properties of the frame/packet are unchanged when it is incoming through one of the port channel's subifs and exiting through the other (give or take NAT rewriting things a bit here and there, but NAT is quite obviously not in use here).

Comment: Marc, can you help me understand how having a SYN coming in from VLAN 306 is going to also show up coming in on VLAN 307.  That's the essence of this question.  If I can get clarity on that (and how it is or isn't an ASA 'feature') then I can mark an answer.  Thanks either way for your reply this is great info !

Comment: I must admit that I am not familiar in detail with the capture feature of the ASA. 

I interpreted the trace output to be just interface related, as they happen to appear on the interface, regardless of direction in/out. 

So the same packet that was inbound on the VLAN306 subif is also seen as outbound on VLAN 307 subif. 

The ever so slight timestamp difference might be a clue there

Comment: ... and documentation suggests that there is no command line parameter for "show cap" that would add the direction of the packet to the display. You may want to consider exporting the capture to e.g. a tftp server in .pcap format.  Analyzing with something like Wireshark and looking at the the src/dst MAC addresses of each frame, you should be able to  determine if a given frame/packet was actually in- or outbound.